# How to use closures in mongodb shell?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, closures, mongodb-shell

I'm kind of confused on how to use closures in mongodb shell.

I want to create a function that i can use **exclusively during development** to quickly look up a document by a part of it's `_id`.

The function should return a `$where` selector that does the necessary matching.
I wanted to write it like this:

```
var id = function(pattern, selector) {
    return Object.extend({
        $where: function() {return (this._id + "").indexOf(pattern) != -1;}
    }, selector);
};
```

But when i try it i get the following error:

```
db.mycollection.find(id("ab1"));
error: {
        "$err" : "JavaScript execution failed: ReferenceError: pattern is not defined near ').indexOf(pattern) ' ",
        "code" : 16722
}
```

Invoking `$where` manually does seem to work oddly enough:

```
id("ell").$where.call({_id: "hello"}); // true
```

I could only think of this as a solution to make it work, but this is obviously terrible.
To clarify: This method with `new Function` works fine, but i don't like it as the above method should work as well.

```
var id = function(pattern, selector){
    return Object.extend({
        $where: new Function("return (this._id + '').indexOf('" + pattern + "') != -1;")
    }, selector);
};
```

- Why is my closure not working, do closures work in mongodb shell ?
- **Bonus question:** Can i register this function somewhere in a user profile to load automatically  ?

Comment: Hmm I am unsure why you think that `find()` expects a closure? In order to run the closure the `find()` function must expect one to be inputted. As for the other question, what do you define as a user profile? Also why would you want to save a `$where` clause globally?

Comment: The problem is not with `find()` but with `$where`. I would have expected for the `pattern` argument from the `id` function to close over the returned `$where` function. But when `$where` is invoked `pattern` is no longer defined.  And I would like to have this `id` function available automatically so i don't have to define it each time i start a new shell. I hope this clarifies the problem a bit.

Comment: Ok I think I know why now, and I beleive it is becuase of how JS works. If you were to define your $where value as a string instead of a `Function` I have a funny feeling it will work. Basically I believe it is evaling your `pattern` var outside of the scope of your client function due to how `Function` works. As for getting this to run without defining it, if you are on Linux you can just add it to the `.mongorc.js` and it will do exactly that

Comment: I don't know MongoDB, but your example [looks correct](http://jsfiddle.net/Mjfsj/). This is either a shortcoming in Mogno's JS engine, or it's a quirk of how `$where` is invoked by the system. Could you try using making an example with `$where: function() { print(pattern) }` and *explicitly invoking it* with `id("abc").$where()`? If explicitly invoking `$where` works, then it's probably an oddity of how `$where` is run when performing a query.

Comment: @apsillers i added your test to my question, invoking `$where` seems to work.

Comment: That $where will not run in the database but instead in the client side through the mongo shell, the js fiddle is wrong since $where is a database operator which must be evaluated within MongoDBs JS envo

Comment: @Sammaye are you sure `$where` does not run on the server, outside the shell ? It's the only way i can now think off how it would lose the closure. If it stringified the function and sends it to the server i could understand the closure gets lost.

Comment: The one provided in the comment I referenced did not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the MongoDB shell serializes (in this case, string-ifies) `$where` function objects in order to send them to the server.

A function in JavaScript is much more than its functional code -- it's part of a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29), which includes both the *function code itself* and the function's *variable referencing environment* for accessing non-local variables. After the function is serialized, it gets unserialized and executed with different referencing environment. When the function tries to reference `pattern`, it's asking for `pattern` in a totally different referencing environment, which does not have a `pattern` variable.

That's why your literal string function works. That function contains the actual value of `pattern`, not the variable identifier `pattern`.

See [this MongoDB bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-150), which explains:

> That would work if the function was being evaluated locally, but the closure isn't sent over automatically.
>
> In babble it used to be, but not in the shell.

This suggests that your code *may* work outside of the shell, but I don't know enough about Mongo internals to say for sure.

Comment: That does seem to be the problem, i will then just use my `new Function` approach which seems to work fine. Thx !